# How to use Laravel Grid View with October CMS on fronted page?

Tags: laravel, gridview, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm am using Octobercsm as a content management system that built on Laravel.
I need to use Laravel Grid View on fronted page ( reference : http://laravel-grid.herokuapp.com )

Comment: If you mean having such grid in the backend of October CMS, then that's actually the way October displays your data in the backend, and you can search, sort, and filter it in the same manner as in the grid you mentioned.